# Alamofire 5: NOT respecting custom HTTP headers

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I followed this tutorial on Medium to write a router for the new Alamofire 5 branch:
https://medium.com/@AladinWay/write-a-networking-layer-in-swift-4-using-alamofire-and-codable-part-1-api-router-349699a47569

The example router is here:
https://github.com/AladinWay/NetworkingExample/blob/master/Networking/APIClient/APIRouter.swift

Headers are being set as such:

```
// Common Headers
urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.acceptType.rawValue)
urlRequest.setValue(ContentType.json.rawValue, forHTTPHeaderField: HTTPHeaderField.contentType.rawValue)
```

However, when I look in Charles Proxy the headers are not actually getting set correctly:

[image]

So it appears that the codebase in this tutorial fails to achieve what it claims to do.

You can reproduce locally on your machine by cloning and running the project and verify that the headers are NOT being set in any packet sniffer:

> git clone https://github.com/AladinWay/NetworkingExample.git

I would like to use Alamofire 5 but how do I actually get the headers to set correctly on the request? I'm assuming I need to configure Alamofire with my own URLSessionConfiguration - something like this?

```
import Alamofire

class APIClient {
@discardableResult
private static func performRequest<T:Decodable>(route:APIRouter,
                                                decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder(),
                                                completion:@escaping (Result<T>)->Void) -> DataRequest {

    var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
    defaultHeaders["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
    defaultHeaders["Accept"] = "application/json"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders

    let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)

    return manager.request(route).responseJSONDecodable (decoder: decoder){ (response: DataResponse<T>) in
            completion(response.result)
    }
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work.
I'm new to Alamofire 5 so I'm not sure how to work with it yet.

Help!

Comment: I have developed same structre suggested in link. with alamofire 4and for me it is working i am not sure about alamofire 5

Comment: hey @etayluz, did you have a solution for this particular scenario? I have followed that blogpost but it does not work with Alamofire 5.

Comment: I have not - but I haven't tried in a year